# iOS unable to send provisioning profile through mdm

Tags: ios, mdm

I have an MDM solution and now I try to send a provisioning profile. So I followed the ios MDM document and send the following profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CommandUUID</key>
        <string>742973d8-3805-4a7d-85ab-7ee715cf7123</string>
        <key>Common</key>
        <dict>
            <key>RequestType</key>
            <string>InstallProvisioningProfile</string>
            <key>ProvisioningProfile</key>
            <data>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</data>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

For some reason this provisioning profile isn't installed on the device and the device returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>Idle</string>
        <key>UDID</key>
        <string>e39165777820d7c5ebd1784224bc2a84ed80a40e</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

So the device sorts of ignore the command. When I send the provisioning profile through Apple Configurator the profile works.

Does anyone knows what I do wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

With help from some good inputs I found the problem.
The problem is that the key should be Command instead of Common. The "error" code is quite strange.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>742973d8-3805-4a7d-85ab-7ee715cf7123</string>
    <key>Command</key>  <--- Here was the error
    <dict>
        <key>RequestType</key>
        <string>InstallProvisioningProfile</string>
        <key>ProvisioningProfile</key>
        <data>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</data>
    </dict>
</dict>
```